# find out how fast my location is changing on Map using core location or map kit

Tags: iphone, xcode, performance, gps, mapkit

I am working on Mapkit and have my current location displayed on Map.Is there any way i can find out the speed of how fast my location is changing.Is there any default property of core location or MKMapview or MKAnnotation class.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You use Core Location to determine their speed.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10) is Apple's documentation on getting Location Services up and running.

Once you are receiving location updates (in the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method) you can access the `speed` property of the CLLocation object that it gives you.